# ArcPad Fill Northing, Easting, Elevation

Tags: esri-geodatabase, arcpad

How do you get ArcPad to fill out the fields for Northing, Easting and Elevation of a point that was created/measured using the GPS on a hand-held unit?

The fields for are part of the geodatabase but I'd like to have them filled in when a point is measured in the field using the hand-held unit.

I have worked with shapefiles in the past but our new equipment is all geodatabase using .axf files for ArcPad. I don't know how to customize an .axf file.

I am a beginner when it comes to scripting and working with these files.

Any information or pointers would be extremely helpful!